Orderer client failed to connect to: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
I'm a beginner in Minifabric and I'm trying to set up a simple network.
These are my .yml files
#org1/spec.yml
   fabric:
     cas:
      - "ca1.org1.example.com"
     peers:
      - "peer1.org1.example.com"
      - "peer2.org1.example.com"
     orderers:
      - "orderer1.example.com"
     netname: "network1"

#org2/spec.yml
   fabric:
     cas:
     - "ca1.org2.example.com"
     peers:
     - "peer1.org2.example.com"
     - "peer2.org2.example.com"
     netname: "network2"
#org3/spec.yml
   fabric:
     cas:
     - "ca1.org3.example.com"
     peers:
     - "peer1.org3.example.com"
     - "peer2.org3.example.com"
     orderers:
     - "orderer2.example.com"
     netname: "network3"

I initialize "Org1" by running the following command inside the directory.
  org1$ minifab netup -e 7100 -o org1.example.com

When I try to create a channel minifab create -c channel1, the following error appears:

I'm trying to do this example to learn.
DETAILS:

I'm developing this example on WSL2.
I'm following the steps on this website to develop an example, but I was blocked on the second command.
I tried disabling the Windows firewall (Defender), but it didn't work either.
I find it strange that Docker works with these ports. I suspect this is the problem, it is trying to connect to one port but is directed to another. I am not an expert in Docker and MiniFabric. The examples I am following on the Internet do not mention any changes in Docker.

The docker log files display the following message: "2024-11-20 16:03:04.734 UTC [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 096 Could not connect to Endpoint: 10.255.255.254:9092, InternalEndpoint: 10.255.255.254:9092, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded"


Get a few steps ahead by not inserting the -e  flag. I don't know why. But now the error is different.
